# Overclock monitoring and stress testing tools in Ubuntu

Tags: overclocking, stress-testing

I would like to know what tools are available to Ubuntu users for monitoring the overclock done in the BIOS and to stress-test the machine. Tools for the following:

1) Tool to reliably read actual clock speeds of the CPU when they are on and off load.

2) Tool to provide bus speeds, RAM speed, graphics core speed etc, in real time.

3) Tool to monitor temperatures.

4) Tool to monitor load on CPU/GPU.

5) Tool to stress test the machine.

Although I want to ask the question with regards to any Ubuntu user with any configuration so that it can be of use to everyone, my configuration is Intel i5 2500k + ASUS P8Z68-V LX, if you must know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needing a tool to do exactly those things, we have created a tool called s-tui. It allows you to monitor CPU frequency/utilization/temperature in real time from the terminal, or over ssh, without event a need for an Xserver.

s-tui also has integrated controls for stress to make it possible to test stability and see possible thermal throttling.

Here is a screen shot.
[image]
Installation is the easiest via pip:
`sudo pip install s-tui`

Other installation methods and more explanations about s-tui is available in github:

https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui

Answer (score 7):

http://code.google.com/p/i7z/

Does all the CPU Clock/Temp monitoring for i3, i5, and i7
You will still need tools to stress the comp.

Also check out this post http://www.overclock.net/t/1177505/checking-overclock-on-ubuntu-11-10/10#post_15893670 Manual way to check the Clock.

Answer (score 5):

The best native tool is HardInfo System information and benchmark tool.

Benchmarks

HardInfo comes with the following benchmark tests:

```
CPU Blowfish
CPU CryptoHash
CPU Fibonacci
CPU N-Queens
FPU FFT
FPU Raytracing
```

Highlighting any test and then selecting 'refresh' from the top toolbar will rerun any previously completed benchmarks

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo
[image]
Found a couple of others

http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=pts_desktop_live

Comment: Thanks, but this tool does not show the CPU speeds correctly. Even after running the command `stress` the CPU speeds are stuck at 1600Mhz. Running any apps do not change it, which is unlikely because the CPU usually jumps to 3300Mhz on load. 1600Mhz is the idle speed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for 14.04**

This is an old link but also works for 14.04, check it out:
[OverclockingCpu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OverclockingCpu)

You might also run into problems running turbostat which doesn't come in the default packages of Ubuntu, but can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-<your kernel version here>-generic
```

Also,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-cloud-tools-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common
```